# Android Camera start delay

Tags: android, camera

I have a tabHost with three activities, one of them is meant for taking pictures and uses the android camera. When I click on this tab for the first time, a blank screen appears for 1-2 seconds before the tabs reappear and the camera preview starts. Is there a way to reduce the delay or at least let the tabs stay while the camera is opened. I tried initialising the camera in a separate thread, but it gave me a runtime exception.

Comment: The solution is loading camera from separated thread. You can read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27869530/camera-open-blocking-ui-thread) or search more about this matter on stackoverflow :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand, you are starting the `Camera` intent from your application, or are you just displaying a preview of the `Camera` feed right on your app? Providing code with your question will help you get better answers.

Are you having this problem on the emulator? If so, it's normal behavior and you shouldn't be worried. If this is on an actual device, I don't think you can really do anything about it. Try loading the `Camera` application by itself and compare times with your application, it shouldn't differ by much.

Ryan

Comment: Thanks for the reply. yes the camera app also takes time to start.